# Performance of the splat operator when accessing a matrix

Tags: arrays, performance, matrix, julia

Let's say we have a matrix and a vector of the indices at which we want to access that matrix:

```
matrix = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 5000, 4000)
point = [1244, 3353]
```

We can use the splat operator (...) to expand the point vector to access the matrix, or we can explicitly use point[1] and point[2] as the indices:

```
matrix[point...]
vs
matrix[point[1], point[2]]
```

The first is more elegant, but apparently also much slower:

```
@btime $matrix[$point...]
70.083 ns (4 allocations: 64 bytes)

@btime $matrix[$point[1], $point[2]]
1.800 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Where does this difference come from? Is there a way to make the splat operator more performant or should I simply use the other solution if I care about performance?

Comment: When you splat a vector, the compiler cannot know beforehand how long it is, so it will just have to start iterating. And it doesn't know with how many inputs args `getindex` will be called, and so on. Directly using `p[1]` and `p[2]` helps with that. But the right way is to use tuples for this, as shown in the answer below. Whenever you are dealing with a short, fixed-length vector, consider using a tuple instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splatting a tuple seems to be as fast as explicit destruction:

```
julia> @btime $matrix[point...] setup=(point = [1244, 3353])
  91.024 ns (4 allocations: 64 bytes)
0.0

julia> @btime $matrix[point[1], point[2]] setup=(point = [1244, 3353])
  2.530 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.0

julia> @btime $matrix[point...] setup=(point = (1244, 3353))
  2.624 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.0

julia> @btime $matrix[point[1], point[2]] setup=(point = (1244, 3353))
  2.255 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.0
```

(I presume the difference between the latter three are mostly insignificant -- in earlier trials, the third "won" over the second.)

Variadic function arguments are internally passed as tuples, so it's no surprise there is no overhead if you directly insert a tuple.

Comment: @akrun I left out the reassignment `point = (1244, 3353)` in the middle, thinking it was clear from the context.

Comment: thanks for the update.  I don't use julia that much so I missed out those things.